# Open Network And Sharing Center programatically without explorer.exe

Tags: c#, windows-10, controlpanel

Is there a way of opening this from a C# application without needing `explorer.exe` to be running? I have a Windows 10 IoT device running with a custom shell, but needs to be able allow the user to set up WiFi connections.

I have tried this:

```
ProcessStartInfo psInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("control.exe", "/name Microsoft.NetworkAndSharingCenter");
```

However while this works fine when running normally in Windows, when I run it in the custom shell (`explorer.exe` is not running), nothing happens.

This differs from the Network Connections applet which runs fine even within the custom shell...

```
ProcessStartInfo psInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("rundll32.exe", "shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL ncpa.cpl");
```

Is there a way to get `rundll32` to run the "Network and Sharing center"? I can't find another .cpl that does it and any research on the 'net just points me back to the original command I tried above.